# HTML/JS Range Slider get number from JS

Tags: javascript, html, slider

I am having some problems with a part of a code I am trying to write for an application.

**I want the background to change depending on the value that the slider produces and which is displayed under the range slider**. But somehow it doesn't seem to be working. I posted a simplified version of the part I am having trouble with below. And I would be super glad if someone could help me.

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.innerHTML = slider.value; // Display the default slider value

// Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
slider.oninput = function() {
    output.innerHTML = this.value;
}
```

```css
.slidecontainer {
    width: 90%;
}


.slider {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 90%;
    height: 25px; 
    outline: none; 
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: .2s; 
    transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none; 
    appearance: none;
    width: 25px; 
    height: 25px; 
    background: #4CAF50; 
    cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
    width: 25px; 
    height: 25px; 
    background: #4CAF50; 
    cursor: pointer; 
}
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="10" value="2" class="slider" id="myRange">
  <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>
  <script type="text/javascript">
         <!--
            var demo = id="demo";
            if( demo == "1" ){
               document.body.style.backgroundColor = "pink";
            }
         
            else if( demo == "2" ){
               document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
            }
         
            else if( demo == "3" ){
               document.body.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
            }
         
            else{
                document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
            }
         //-->
      </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any of that `if/else` script at all. Just set up the possible colors in an array and then right after you show the value of the slider, get the color out of the array that matches the index of the slider value and set the color to that.

Also (FYI), there's no need for `-webkit-transition` as the CSS `transition` property has been standard for several years now and is supported in all current browsers.

Lastly, don't use `.innerHTML` when you aren't setting/getting any HTML. Use `.textContent` for plain text.

```js
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("demo");
output.textContent = slider.value; // Display the default slider value

// The slider has 10 possible positions, so we set up an array with 10 colors:
var colors = ["pink", "green", "blue", "red", "orange", "aqua", "yellow", "salmon", "silver", "purple"];

// Update the current slider value (each time you drag the slider handle)
slider.oninput = function() {
    output.textContent = this.value;
    // Just set the page color to the color from the array that matches
    // the slider's value (array indexes start from 0, so slider value
    // has to be adjusted by one).
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = colors[+this.value - 1];
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color:grey;
}

.slidecontainer {
    width: 90%;
}

.slider {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    width: 90%;
    height: 25px; 
    outline: none; 
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity .2s;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    -webkit-appearance: none; 
    appearance: none;
    width: 25px; 
    height: 25px; 
    background: #4CAF50; 
    cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
    width: 25px; 
    height: 25px; 
    background: #4CAF50; 
    cursor: pointer; 
}
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer">
  <input type="range" min="1" max="10" value="2" class="slider" id="myRange">
  <p>Value: <span id="demo"></span></p>

</div>
```